# Find and replace values in a valueholder in an ini file with notepadd++?

Tags: notepad++

I have an ini file with a repeated value holder called `pRecord=` and it has a value after it. I want to replace the value with 0 but it can be between 1 and 5 digits.

Example:

```
pRecord=23
pRecord=223
pRecord=345
pRecord=2234
pRecord=15321
```

I now want them all to be `pRecord=` or `pRecord=0`, but I can't figure out how to to it correctly with the find and replace feature of notepad++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `pRecord=\K\d+`
- Replace with: `0`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
pRecord=        # literally
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
\d+             # 1 or more digit
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]